# External srt subtitles are not showing in apple tv when air played from ios app

Tags: apple-tv, airplay, subtitle, srt

Hi I am using external srt files to show subtitles in my ios app using UILabel. But the same subtitles doesn't show up when I air play the same video to Apple TV. Is there anyway we can show subtitles in Apple TV airplay when subtitles are coming from an external srt files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AppleTV can't play external SRT files, only hardcoded soft coded subtitles works, You can check apple stream example

> https://tungsten.aaplimg.com/VOD/bipbop_adv_example_hevc/master.m3u8